# Transform PointZ/LinestringZ/PolygonZ's z-coordiante values from feet to meters in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS there is the ST_Transform() function that can re-project the XY coordinates of Point/Linestring/Polygon/etc to another coordinates system including meters-based projection to a feet-based projection system.

Is there a similar function or method to transform the z-values of vector geometries from meters to feet or vice versa?

I am storing my z-values in my database as meters but sometimes I need to return them in a view as feet z-values

Answer (score 1):

You can scale just the Z coordinate with ST_Scale https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Scale.html
The first example modified to convert Z values from meters to feet

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_Scale(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(1 2 3, 1 1 1)'), 1, 1, 3.280839895));
Result:
LINESTRING(1 2 9.842519685000001,1 1 3.280839895)
```

Comment: That answers my question and solves that problem but I one additional note.
If one tries it with a ZM geometry and you also need to scale the m/distance value for geocoding, the scale factors have to be used as a point (SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_Scale(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(1 2 3 0, 1 1 1 1.3)'), ST_MakePoint(1,1, 3.280839895,3.280839895))); ).

Comment: Right, just as documented in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Scale.html.